# Split a word with regexp in matlab; startIndex for 'split'?

Tags: regex, string, matlab, split, phonetics

My aim is to generate the phonetic transcription for any word according to a set of rules.

First, I want to split words into their syllables. For example, I want an algorithm to find 'ch' in a word and then separate it like shown below:

```
Input: 'aachbutcher'
Output: 'a' 'a' 'ch' 'b' 'u' 't' 'ch' 'e' 'r'
```

I have come so far:

```
check=regexp('aachbutcher','ch');

if (isempty(check{1,1})==0)          % Returns 0, when 'ch' was found.

   [match split startIndex endIndex] = regexp('aachbutcher','ch','match','split')

   %Now I split the 'aa', 'but' and 'er' into single characters:
   for i = 1:length(split)
       SingleLetters{i} = regexp(split{1,i},'.','match');
   end

end
```

My problem is: How do I put the cells together, such that they are formatted like the desired output? I only have the starting indexes for the match parts ('ch') but not for the split parts ('aa', 'but','er').

Any ideas?

Comment: Take the diff of `startIndex` to get the lengths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to work with the indices or length. Simple logic: Process first element from match, then first from split, then second from match etc....

```
[match,split,startIndex,endIndex] = regexp('aachbutcher','ch','match','split');

%Now I split the 'aa', 'but' and 'er' into single characters:
SingleLetters=regexp(split{1,1},'.','match');

for i = 2:length(split)
   SingleLetters=[SingleLetters,match{i-1},regexp(split{1,i},'.','match')];
end
```

Comment: worked perfectly, thanks! can you correct the typo in the third line (the 'i'). I thought that method would not work when the word starts with 'ch', but luckily split{1,1} is an empty entry in that case.

Answer (score 0):

So, you know the length of 'ch', it's 2. You know where you found it from regex, as those indices are stored in startIndex. I'm **assuming** (Please, correct me if I'm wrong) that you want to split all other letters of the word into single-letter cells, like in your output above. So, you can just use the startIndex data to construct your output, using conditionals, like this:

```
check=regexp('aachbutcher','ch');

if (isempty(check{1,1})==0)          % Returns 0, when 'ch' was found.

    [match split startIndex endIndex] = regexp('aachbutcher','ch','match','split')

    %Now I split the 'aa', 'but' and 'er' into single characters:
    for i = 1:length(split)
       SingleLetters{i} = regexp(split{1,i},'.','match');
    end

end

j = 0;
for i = 1 : length('aachbutcher')
    if (i ~= startIndex(1)) && (i ~= startIndex(2)) 
        j = j +1;
        output{end+1} = SingleLetters{j};
    else
        i = i + 1;    
        output{end+1} = 'ch';
    end
end
```

I don't have MATLAB right now, so I can't test it. I hope it works for you! If not, let me know and I'll take anther shot at it.